# Use Large pages in Jboss

Tags: java, performance, jvm, paging, jboss5.x

I was going through the JBOSS manual where I read about [LARGEPAGES](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Java_Virtual_Machine_Tuning-Large_Page_Memory.html).
We have allocated more than 10GB to heap.

I want to know whether really do we get any benefits of using this? Or is there any sideeffects of doing this?
Is there any tool or utility which will lets us know the pages that are being created.Basically I want to analyse the page related performance

**What I have done till now is below:**
1)Changed my local security policy in windows where jboss is running to include the user account which will be running the Jboss.Do I need to do this where jboss is running or where database is running ?

2)Added -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=2m to the jboss startup script.

---

Is there anything else apart from above which needs to be done or I need to take care of ?

Machine details
a)windows server 8
b)processor:intel xeon

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion 10G Heap for Web Application server like JBoss Etc are very huge.

Big heap size means, it need more Full GC Time. As u know in full GC time, it will freeze the world.

Is there any specific reason to use such big memory?

If you have big memory in a box, i recommend to run # of Jboss instance in a box and load balace by using reverse proxy. It will be more efficient.

Comment: I wasnt aware of the repercussions of having big heap size.We have been using this for some time now.We have got 4 instances of the Jboss running with each having 10gb heap size.Our application is huge and lot of concurrent requests are being handled which explains the provision of such huge heap.Does it really matter?Will it really  make an impact considering we are using 64 bit system.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS as to how large pages are handled and whether they really help.  For example if you have a processor up to Sandy Bridge, it can have up to 8 large pages in the TLB cache. For the latest Haswell, it can have up to 1024 which is obviously a big difference.

In some versions of Linux you have to reserve the large pages in advance and there may be an advantage in pre-allocating this memory.

However, I am not aware of any big performance advantages in using large pages in the JVM. esp for larger heaps and pre-Haswell processors.

BTW 10 GB isn't that big these days.  The limit for CompressesOops is around 30 GB and up to this is a medium sizes heap IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for providing your insight.I have edited my question and added more details.OS is windows server.please let me know if you have any comments for this.

Comment: @Rips you need to know which generation of processor you have.  Unless it is 4th generation I wouldn't expect large pages to work very well.

Comment: My processor is XEon(R)CPU X5570-2.93GHZ(8 processors).Also I wanted to know whether I need to enable Use Large memory on the system where Database is installed or the one where application is installed.

Comment: @Rips This is a very good processor which has 4 core, 8 cpus with HT, but I wouldn't expect this to perform so well with large pages.